# Can I use leaflet for EPSG:4326 rectangular map

Tags: leaflet

I would like to draw a map in 2D but not in spherical mercator projection with square tiles, but with EPSG:4326 with rectangular tiles (so it will be a rectangular planisphere).

Is it possible to do that with leaflet ? If no, is there an alternative map engine that could do that with HTML5 Canvas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently rectangular tiles aren't implemented in Leaflet because there was no use case for it, but you can do that with a bit of hacking (see TileLayer.js in the source) — it's pretty straightforward.